# Monitoring Bluecats Beacons in Background or When app is not running

Tags: ios, swift, background, ibeacon

I am using bluecats beacons for my app.  I want to detect if user enters the beacon region when user app is not running, i want to show a local notification that user has entered the beacon region

Here's My Code: **The App Delegate class**

```
var beaconManager = BCBeaconManager()
var beacon_region: BCBeaconRegion!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    beaconManager.delegate = self

    self.requestAuthorizationForLocalNotifications()

    BlueCatsSDK.startPurring(withAppToken: "7d17d7cb-8a26-4b8b-999f-9b031deab7a5", completion: { (BCStatus) -> Void in
        let appTokenVerificationStatus: BCAppTokenVerificationStatus = BlueCatsSDK.appTokenVerificationStatus()
        if (appTokenVerificationStatus == .notProvided || appTokenVerificationStatus == .invalid){
        }
        if (!BlueCatsSDK.isLocationAuthorized()){

            BlueCatsSDK.requestAlwaysLocationAuthorization()
        }
        if (!BlueCatsSDK.isNetworkReachable()){
        }
        if (!BlueCatsSDK.isBluetoothEnabled()){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Turn On Bluetooth", message: "This App requires that Bluetooth is enabled to process your orders", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Don’t Allow", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Allow", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    })

    self.beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconRegion(beacon_region)

    return true
}

// On Exit
func beaconManager(_ beaconManager: BCBeaconManager!, didExitSite site: BCSite!) {
    PresentNotifications(title: "You exited the region")
}

// On Enter
func beaconManager(_ beaconManager: BCBeaconManager!, didEnter site: BCSite!) {
   PresentNotifications(title: "You Entered the region")
}


func beaconManager(_ beaconManager: BCBeaconManager!, didDetermineState state: BCSiteState, for site: BCSite!) {
    if state == BCSiteState.inside{
        PresentNotifications(title: "You are inside the region")
    }
    else if state == BCSiteState.outside{
        PresentNotifications(title: "You are outside the region")
    }
    else{
        return
    }
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconRegion(beacon_region)
}
```

Comment: It may be that the BlueCats SDK does not support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Apps interact with beacons in 2 ways:
1) Monitoring: Actions triggered when the app enters/exit the regions range. works no matter whether the app is running, suspended, or killed (if the app's not running when an enter/exit events comes, iOS will launch it into the background for a few seconds to handle the event). 
2) Ranging: Action triggers based on the proximity to a beacon. This will work only when the app is running.

So in-order to make iOS awake our app when it is not running you can use monitoring. But Monitoring is having some limitations. It only recognizes enter/exit events and provides no information about which exact beacon triggered the event (only which region did), and no proximity estimations. 
         You can, however, use the time iOS grants your app to handle the enter/exit event to run ranging for a few seconds, and learn both which exact beacons are in range, and what's their proximity.